# asp-for to table connected relations one-to-many

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Hello i have two tables: Restaurants and Reviews

**Restaurants.cs**

```
 public class Restaurants
    {
        [Key]
        public int RestaurantsId { get; set; }

        public string Name{ get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Reviews> Reviews{ get; set; }

    }
```

**Reviews.cs**

```
public class Reviews
    {
        [Key]
        public int ReviewsId { get; set; }


        public string { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey("Restaurants")]
        public int RestaurantsId { get; set; }

        public virtual Restaurants Restaurants{ get; set; }

    }
```

In "Restaurant detail view" I displays data from the Restaurants table for one restaurant. I would like to add opinions there regarding a given restaurant.

If i have one to one relation i create something like this

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Reviews.RestaurantsId" value="@Model.IdRestauracji" />

....
```

and it work. It is possible create something like this, but i have one-to-many relation? Exactly, I mean adding a reference to the table **Reviews** in asp-for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One input can bind one of the reviews.If you want to bind the reviews of the Model,you can use @foreach:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Reviews)
{
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.ReviewsId" value="@item.ReviewsId"  id="@item.RestaurantsId"/>
}
```